# Weird Namespacing context behavior with JS in Dynamics 365 Ribbon button

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics

I have following Javascript code written for my Dynamics 365 Ribbon button click event.

```
var SampleNamespace = SampleNamespace || {};
SampleNamespace = {
 someVariable : 'xyz',
 clickMeFromRibbon: function(){
  // this = window in classic UI | this.iWillDoSomething() - Error
  // this = SampleNamespace in Modern UUI | this.iWillDoSomething() - Works fine
 },
 iWilDoSomething : function(){
  // Doing some other helper operations
 }
}
```

in Ribbon button click I have specified following function to be called

```
SampleNamespace.clickMeFromRibbon
```

any idea why reference of `this` is different and how can we solve that with the effective namespacing working in both the environment?

PS : I have tried multiple types of different namespacing available in javascript but all resulted into same issue.

Comment: Why do you need "this"?

Comment: @AndrewButenko I have just updated my question, the problem is when I want to call this.iWillDoSomething(), I can easily call SampleNamespace.iWillDoSomething() which works in both the cases of classic and UUI, but don't want to repeat namespace name everywhere. Hope that makes it bit clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different way working with namespaces that works fine for me:

```js
var SampleNamespace = (function(){
    var someVariable = "xyz";

    function clickMeFromRibbon(){
        //you can call iWilDoSomething from here without using namespaces
    }

    function iWilDoSomething(){
    }

    return {
        clickMeFromRibbon: clickMeFromRibbon,
        iWilDoSomething: iWilDoSomething
    };
})();

//Also SampleNamespace.clickMeFromRibbon and SampleNamespace.iWilDoSomething are available externally
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I just found that exactly the way after so much of brainstorming, but will accept this as answer as you did just before I can post mine. Name-spacing is art when it comes to JS.